# Importing multiple CSV files into one BigQuery table

Tags: excel, google-bigquery, coursera-api

I am trying to finish my Google Data Analytics capstone case study using a DIVVY bike-share data set. The annual data is broken up into monthly Excel workbooks and I am trying to get all the data into one table on my free BigQuery sandbox project.

I have tried merging all the Excel files into one workbook, but there are over 5M rows of data, which is too large to merge in Excel. To work around this, I have tried uploading the individual months as separate tables in my BigQuery project and then using a temporary table to combine the tables using the UNION ALL function. This has not worked because when I run the query, I get an error saying that the free sandbox version of BigQuery does not support DML queries and that you have to upgrade to a paid account to run DML functions.

Has anyone working through this case study project encountered similar issues, have a solution to upload all the data into one table, or have a resource for another free SQL platform? I want to do the analysis in SQL as I am not the best at using R. Thanks in advance.

Comment: As long as you have all of your CSVs into same schema, you can use a wildcard notation when you upload into a table. 
e.g. if ur files are like: case_study_jan, case_study_feb,... then u case just use standard load API or through standard UI for creating a new table , select source as gcs or local and provide a wild card location path like .../case_study_* this will force all load going into same destination table that you will provide